# Registering PHP Session Variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to create a simple login form. I have `session_start()`; as the first thing loaded on the page. I have a file login.php which contains the login related code which is processed through an ajax call when the Login button is clicked. It contains:

```
if ($_GET['cemail']) {

$email = $_GET['cemail']; 
$password = md5($_GET['cpassword']); 
$sql = "select * from users where email='" . $email . "' and password='" . $password . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) { 
    session_register("email");
}
else {
    echo "<span style='color:#ffffff;'>Invalid Email/Password</span><br>";
}

}
```

When I click the Login button, I get this warning:

> Warning: session_register() [function.session-register]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/clicker/public_html/hstrial-RBochner/login.php:1) in /home/clicker/public_html/hstrial-RBochner/login.php on line 82

Line 82 is the line that says `session_register("email")`;

I also tried to create a Logout button which just calls `session_destroy()`, but it gives me this:

> Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /home/clicker/public_html/hstrial-RBochner/login.php on line 66

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried placing `session_start()` in various places. Any help/ideas? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent, Why its happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827314/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-why-its-happening)

Comment: `session_register` is deprecated and scheduled to be removed from the language. You shouldn't be using it at all.. if you found that in some tutorial, it's probably from a decade ago.

Comment: This might be the single most common PHP problem. The answer is clearly documented *everywhere*. Please get in the habit of googling your error message and searching SO for existing questions/answers before asking a new question. The manual for [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) contains dozens of answers.

Comment: try put session_start() in first line of your code. 

and 
instance of:
session_register("email");

do this:
$_SESSION['email'] = 'baa';

Comment: Not what you were asking but you probably want to do some validation on that $_GET['cemail']. You are opening yourself up to all kinds of nasty SQL injection.

Comment: As @Bill Heller says, please validate your input!

Answer (score 6):

you need:

1. put session_start() in start of your code
2. don't use session_register(), is an obsolete function, replace by $_SESSION['foo'] = 'baa';
3. destruct session:

   session_start();
   session_destroy();
4. your web application is vulnerably to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. 
   -check [best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I do not agree with your third point - unset($_SESSION); is wrong - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#77926

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that if the session works without session_start(), then session.auto_start should be turned off and started explicitly otherwise every request which hits PHP will load (and lock) the session.

Answer (score 1):

about your logout-button question. You have to start your session first

```
<?php
//logout.php
session_start();
session_destroy();
echo "Logouted"
```

instead of

```
  session_register()
```

use just

```
   $_SESSION['email'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read over at the `session_register()` PHP documentation ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)), it seems that `session_register()` is deprecated and that `$_SESSION["email"] = "email@example.com";` is the new way to do it as of PHP 4.1.0.

A code example would then be (I am not sure if this works tho, but it should guide you in the right direction);

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['cemail']) {
        $email = $_GET['cemail']; 
        $password = md5($_GET['cpassword']); 
        $sql = "select * from users where email='" . $email . "' and password='" . $password . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) { 
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        }
        else {
            echo "<span style='color:#ffffff;'>Invalid Email/Password</span><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

For the logout you would then do:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    session_destroy();
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    session_start();  
    if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
        unset($_SESSION['email']); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by putting all php code at the very beginning of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Move session_register before you execute a print or echo.